# Drawing images on top of Paths in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am modifying [this swift radar chart](https://betterprogramming.pub/data-visualization-with-swiftui-radar-charts-64124aa2ac0b). I would like to draw an image on each of the edge vertices. I cannot figure out how to draw an image at the same time as drawing a path. Barring that, I figured I could let the shape draw itself and then somehow recover the edge vertices from its path and draw images as overlays on the shape, but I cannot figure out how to get those vertices.

So I have two questions, and I only need to know the answer to **one** of them to proceed.

1. How can I draw an image at the same time as drawing a path?
2. How can I pull out the edge vertices of this shape and then use them to draw overlays on the shape (the code below is closer to this version, but I'd rather be able to draw the images at the same time as drawing the path).

```
import SwiftUI

struct RadarChart: View {
    var data: [Double]
    let gridColor: Color
    let dataColor: Color
    
    private var edgeVertices: [CGPoint]
    
    init(data: [Double], gridColor: Color = .gray, dataColor: Color = .blue) {
        self.data = data
        self.gridColor = gridColor
        self.dataColor = dataColor
        self.edgeVertices = []
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                RadarChartGrid(categories: data.count, divisions: 5)
                    .stroke(gridColor, lineWidth: 0.5)
                    .overlay(
                        Image(systemName: "star")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width:20)
                            .position(x: geo.size.width/2, y: geo.size.height/2)
                    )
                
                RadarChartPath(data: data)
                    .fill(dataColor.opacity(0.3))
                
                RadarChartPath(data: data)
                    .stroke(dataColor, lineWidth: 2.0)
            }
            .padding(20)
        }
    }
}

struct RadarChartGrid: Shape {
    let categories: Int
    let divisions: Int
    
    private func calculateEdgePoints(rect: CGRect) -> [CGPoint]{
        var edgeVertices: [CGPoint] = []
        
        let radius = min(rect.maxX - rect.midX, rect.maxY - rect.midY)
        for category in 1 ... categories {
            let edgePoint = CGPoint(x: rect.midX + cos(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * radius,
                           y: rect.midY + sin(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * radius)
            edgeVertices.append(edgePoint)
        }
        
        return edgeVertices
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let radius = min(rect.maxX - rect.midX, rect.maxY - rect.midY)
        let stride = radius / CGFloat(divisions)
        var path = Path()
        
        for category in 1 ... categories {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + cos(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * radius,
                                     y: rect.midY + sin(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * radius))
        }
        
        for step in 1 ... divisions {
            let rad = CGFloat(step) * stride
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + cos(-.pi / 2) * rad,
                                  y: rect.midY + sin(-.pi / 2) * rad))
            
            for category in 1 ... categories {
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + cos(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * rad,
                                         y: rect.midY + sin(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * rad))
            }
        }
        
        return path
    }
}

struct RadarChartPath: Shape {
    let data: [Double]
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        guard
            3 <= data.count,
            let minimum = data.min(),
            0 <= minimum,
            let maximum = data.max()
        else { return Path() }
        
        let radius = min(rect.maxX - rect.midX, rect.maxY - rect.midY)
        var path = Path()
        
        for (index, entry) in data.enumerated() {
            switch index {
            case 0:
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + CGFloat(entry / maximum) * cos(CGFloat(index) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(data.count) - .pi / 2) * radius,
                                      y: rect.midY + CGFloat(entry / maximum) * sin(CGFloat(index) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(data.count) - .pi / 2) * radius))
                
            default:
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + CGFloat(entry / maximum) * cos(CGFloat(index) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(data.count) - .pi / 2) * radius,
                                         y: rect.midY + CGFloat(entry / maximum) * sin(CGFloat(index) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(data.count) - .pi / 2) * radius))
            }
        }
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

struct RadarChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RadarChart(data: [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3])
    }
}
```

The above code produces this image. Note that I would like to put a different image on each vertex, but cannot figure out how to get the vertices.

[image]

Comment: If your deployment target is iOS 15 or later, you'll probably find it easier to draw the whole chart including images using [`Canvas`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/canvas#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity and for anyone who also struggled in piecing together how to do stuff on the canvas, here is an implementation following what @rob mayoff said by drawing everything on the canvas.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RadarChart: View {
    var data: [Double]
    let gridColor: Color
    let fillColor: Color
    let strokeColor: Color
    let divisions: Int
    let radiusBuffer: Double
    
    init(data: [Double], gridColor: Color = .gray, fillColor: Color = .blue, strokeColor: Color = .blue, divisions: Int = 10, radiusBuffer: Double = 0.0) {
        self.data = data
        self.gridColor = gridColor
        self.fillColor = fillColor
        self.strokeColor = strokeColor
        self.divisions = divisions
        self.radiusBuffer = radiusBuffer
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            let edges = calculateEdgePoints(rect: context.clipBoundingRect, categories: data.count)
            let radarCharGridPath = radarChartGridPath(in: context.clipBoundingRect, categories: data.count)
            let dataPath = radarChartPath(in: context.clipBoundingRect)
            
            context.stroke(radarCharGridPath, with: .color(gridColor), lineWidth: 0.5)
            context.fill(dataPath, with: .color(fillColor.opacity(0.3)))
            context.stroke(dataPath, with: .color(strokeColor), lineWidth: 2.0)
            
            for idx in 0...data.count-1 {
                var edge = edges[idx]
                let image = Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                let imageEdgeSize = 20.0
                edge.x -= imageEdgeSize / 2
                edge.y -= imageEdgeSize / 2
                let rect = CGRect(origin: edge, size: CGSize(width:imageEdgeSize, height:imageEdgeSize))
                context.draw(image, in: rect)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Radar Chart")
    }
    
    private func calculateEdgePoints(rect: CGRect, categories: Int) -> [CGPoint] {
        var edgeVertices: [CGPoint] = []
        
        let radius = min(rect.maxX - rect.midX, rect.maxY - rect.midY) - radiusBuffer
        print("Edgepoints radius: \(radius)")
        for category in 1 ... categories {
            let edgePoint = CGPoint(x: rect.midX + cos(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * radius,
                                    y: rect.midY + sin(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * radius)
            edgeVertices.append(edgePoint)
        }
        
        return edgeVertices
    }
    
    func radarChartGridPath(in rect: CGRect, categories: Int) -> Path {
        let radius = min(rect.maxX - rect.midX, rect.maxY - rect.midY) - radiusBuffer
        let stride = radius / CGFloat(divisions)
        var path = Path()
        
        for category in 1 ... categories {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + cos(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * radius,
                                     y: rect.midY + sin(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * radius))
        }
        
        for step in 1 ... divisions {
            let rad = CGFloat(step) * stride
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + cos(-.pi / 2) * rad,
                                  y: rect.midY + sin(-.pi / 2) * rad))
            
            for category in 1 ... categories {
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + cos(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * rad,
                                         y: rect.midY + sin(CGFloat(category) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(categories) - .pi / 2) * rad))
            }
        }
        
        return path
    }
    
    func radarChartPath(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        guard
            3 <= data.count,
            let minimum = data.min(),
            0 <= minimum,
            let maximum = data.max()
        else { return Path() }
        
        let radius = min(rect.maxX - rect.midX, rect.maxY - rect.midY) - radiusBuffer
        var path = Path()
        
        for (index, entry) in data.enumerated() {
            switch index {
            case 0:
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + CGFloat(entry / maximum) * cos(CGFloat(index) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(data.count) - .pi / 2) * radius,
                                      y: rect.midY + CGFloat(entry / maximum) * sin(CGFloat(index) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(data.count) - .pi / 2) * radius))
                
            default:
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + CGFloat(entry / maximum) * cos(CGFloat(index) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(data.count) - .pi / 2) * radius,
                                         y: rect.midY + CGFloat(entry / maximum) * sin(CGFloat(index) * 2 * .pi / CGFloat(data.count) - .pi / 2) * radius))
            }
        }
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

func makeList(_ n: Int) -> [Double] {
    return (0..<n).map{ _ in Double.random(in: 1 ... 20) }
}

struct RadarChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RadarChart(
            data: makeList(30),
            divisions: 5,
            radiusBuffer: 10
        )
            .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]